# Processing a cell value in Pandas and outputing to same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains data regarding emails. Within the column, 'Recipients', I have email address values. What I am looking to do is check if the email address in each row contains 'gmail' and if so, in a new column called 'New Column', I want to write 'to be checked'. Here's my code. It doesn't seem to write to a new column though:-

```
for y in df['Recipients']:
    if 'gmail' in y:
        try:
            df['New Column'] = 'to be checked'
        except:
            continue

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Any ideas what may be wrong? It is iterating fine and when I print to screen, it prints the different email addresses but just doesn't seem to populate a new column called 'New Column' with 'to be checked'

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['contains_gmail']=df['Recipients'].str.contains('gmail')
```

or as you wanted:

```
df.loc[df['Recipients'].str.contains('gmail'),'new columns']="to be checked"
```